# How to get children of a particular parent (parent id) and displaying output in genealogy tree

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to output the children data from database of a particular parent using the parent id to a genealogy tree.

i'm new to php, but i have been able to get to display the whole tree starting from the top.

```
function getChildren($parent) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM member_log WHERE parent_id = $parent";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$children = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $children[$i] = array();
    $children[$i]['username'] = $row['username'];
    $children[$i]['children'] = getChildren($row['id'] );
$i++;
}
return $children;
}

$finalResult = getChildren('0');

function printList($array = null) {
    if (count($array)) {
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach ($array as $item) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href= \"#\"> " . $item['username'] . "</a>";
            if (count($item['children'])) {
                printList($item['children']);
            }
            echo "</li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

and this to get result

```
printList();
```

id   |   parent id   |     name       |
1    |        0      |   1st user     |
2    |        1      |   2nd user     |
3    |        1      |   3rd user     |
4    |        1      |   4th user     |
6    |        2      |   5th user     |
7    |        2      |   6th user     |
8    |        2      |   7th user     |

such that if i want to get all the children of 2nd user, i should get 5th, 6th and 7th user. And i 1st user would have 2nd, 3rd and 4th user as children and 5th, 6th and 7th as grand children.

Comment: don't use `mysql_*` . it's deprecated now. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: you already define the `$children` 
`$children = array();`
don't define again here 
`$children[$i] = array();` -> this is an array already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this url:-[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

And solution for current problem is:-

```
function getChildren($parent) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM member_log WHERE parent_id = $parent";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $children = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $children[$row['id']]['username'] = $row['username'];
        $children[$row['id']]['children'] = getChildren( $row['id'] );
    }
    return $children;
}
```

Comment: @OtunMusaBashir  glad to help you. But please check the Url what i have given and immediately move towards PHP7 along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: thanks @Alive to Die, i already did and its all in mysqli_ now

Comment: Please what if i want to get the count of child nodes instead?

Comment: @OtunMusaBashir  Please ask a new question regarding that. someone will answer for-sure. Add proper input data,your-effort and expected outcome, in the new question. drop the question link here. if i will be free, i will look to that and will try to answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811611/how-to-get-total-count-of-child-node-from-a-recursive-parent-child-tree